# Plotly: Different setups for two plots in one frame

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(
    Category = c('foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo'),
    x = c(2.1, 3.4, 4, 4),
    y = c(16, 21, 10, 17)
)

palette <- c("green", "red")

fig <- plot_ly(
    data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y, size = 10, color = ~Category, colors = palette,
    symbol = ~Category, hoverinfo = 'y', symbols = c(15, 17)
)
fig
```

That's what I have so far. What I want to do is to make the `foo` plot, and only the `foo` plot, visible in the legend. I've tried using `add_trace()` with `showlegend = F`, but that sets `bar` invisible in the legend as well.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't it better to use `ggplot2`?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Category = c('foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo'),
  x = c(2.1, 3.4, 4, 4),
  y = c(16, 21, 10, 17)
)


df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(Category=='foo'), aes(x, y, col=Category, shape=Category))+
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(Category=='bar'), aes(x, y), col="green", shape=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I have my reasons for using plotly. I would like to know how to solve my problem there.